# rename using a do loop in R?

Tags: r

I want to rename columns 1 to 206

```
names(country)[1] <- Multiple_Choices[[170,2]]
names(country)[206] <- Multiple_Choices[[375,2]]
```

Is the best way of doing this in R writing a loop that goes from 1 to 206?

```
for (i in 1:206 ) {
  names(country)[i] <- Multiple_Choices[[169+i,2]]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need, you can do all this in one line in R:

```
names(country)[1:206] <- Multiple_Choices[170:375,2]
```

Comment: I get an error: "Error in Multiple_Choices[[170:375, 2]] : 
  attempt to select more than one element"

Comment: Use  `[` if you want to select more than one element: `Multiple_Choices[170:375, 2]`. This is documented in `help("[")`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still trying to learn when to use [] and when [[]]